# Find by element and send keys not working for second time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using some python code with the Chrome webdriver to login to a website.

I am finding the element by id then entering both username and Password.

It works well for the first element entry be it username or password but it's not working for the following element. It is getting stuck at the find element by id statement.

Here is my code,

```
chromedriver = "C:\\Users\\testuser\\Desktop\\chrome\\chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://*****/login/")
print 1 
Password1= driver.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys("******")
print 2
Username1= driver.find_element_by_id("Username").send_keys("******")
```

The code stops after print 2, it is not detecting the second find element by id.

Comment: post the elements HTML

Comment: Sometimes id's are generated dynamically. are you sure that's not the case.

Comment: What version of Chrome and what version of the Chrome Driver?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. I can execute ONE command after finding something and then the next command hangs. For example if I find a "Username" element and use "send_keys()", any further commands to the Driver will hang (including "click(), send_keys(), find_*()).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding calls to `click`:

```
elt = driver.find_element_by_id("Password")
elt.click()
elt.send_keys("******")
elt = driver.find_element_by_id("Username")
elt.click()
elt.send_keys("******")
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. But Click also i have tried already and tried once again now. But My problem is on the find part of the element. It actually gets stuck in finding the element which is before click. Click action comes only after that. Note: The click works well for the first element (Username).

Comment: Can you post the HTML around the Password and Username `<inputs>`?

Comment: Hi Please, Find the XML                                                     <div class="InputBox">
 <label for="Password">Password</label>
 <input type="password" id="Password" name="UserPassword"> 
 <a href="https://s.test.com/ControlPanel/#reset" class="ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

1) Use WebDriverWait:

> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
>   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Username")));

2)or Maybe bewebdriver not able to find elment on page,so in that case, use other locators like, xpath.

Hope it'll help you :)

Comment: We have Tried Xpath already. I think its a problem with the Chrome. The code with chrome Webdriver reacts different for each machine. I will try the the webdirverwait. (We have done already a wait by a sleep statement of 40 seconds, if that is the intention with webdriver wait)

Answer (score 0):

1. add some wait with timeout, before typing
2. or when your browser saving every filed, it would be wise to add blbla.clear(); before bla.sendkeys();